# what are the actual consequences of kundalini yoga?

Tags: yoga, moksha, spiritual-level, kundalini

I have been reading about Kundalini yoga and have realized that though people consider the Kundilini arousal state to be the consequence of spiritual enlightenment, the after-effects of this arousal have surreal outcomes which cannot be explained by Physiologists. So my question is, in the history, what was believed to be the outcome of this yoga?

When I searched about this in the net, the only abstract answer to this question I got was, "It causes spiritual enlightenment". More than finding information on the good side of this yoga's outcome, I find information on the bad side of this yoga, and also suggestions on what must be done if someone experiences this state.

But my question is, what was believed to be the goal motive for yogis in the past in performing this yoga, and what is the actual necessity of this yoga? Why would anyone want to do a yoga that has a bunch of negative effects but not a single clear positive effect? I want to know what the Hindu books have got to say about this.

Answer (score 7):

You can read Sri Ramakrishna's experience given in 'The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna'. Here is an excerpt from 'The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna':

> **A man's spiritual consciousness is not awakened unless his Kundalini
>   is aroused**.    The Kundalini dwells in the Muladhara. When it is
>   aroused, it passes along the Sushumna nerve, goes through the centres
>   of Svadhisthana, Manipura, and so on, and at last reaches the head.
>   This is called the movement of the Mahavayu, the Spiritual Current. It
>   culminates in Samadhi.   One's spiritual consciousness is not awakened
>   by the mere reading of books. One should also pray to God. The
>   Kundalini is aroused if the aspirant feels restless for God. To talk
>   of knowledge from mere study and hearsay! What will that accomplish?
>   Just before my attaining this state of mind, it has been revealed to
>   me how the Kundalini is aroused, how the lotuses of the different
>   centres blossom forth, and how this culminates in Samadhi. This is a
>   very secret experience. I saw a boy twenty-two or twenty-three years
>   old, exactly resembling me, enter the Sushumna nerve and commune with
>   the lotuses, touching them with his tongue. He began with the center
>   at the anus and passed through the centres at the sexual organ, navel,
>   and so on. The different lotuses of these centres - four petalled,
>   six-petalled, ten-petalled, and so forth- had been drooping. At his
>   touch they stood erect.   When he reached the heart - I distinctly
>   remember it- and communed with the lotus there, touching it with his
>   tongue, the twelve-petalled lotus, which was hanging head down, stood
>   erect and opened its petals. Then he came to the sixteen-petalled
>   lotus in the throat and the two petalled lotus in the forehead. And
>   last of all, the thousand-petalled lotus in the head blossomed. Since
>   then I have been in this state.

Sri Ramakrishna in The Gospel of Sri Ramakrishna on August 9, 1885.

Comment: I understand that. but my real question is, why should one want the kundalini to raise to their head? What are the other reasons for it, other than attaining spiritual enlightenment?

Comment: The main reason is that raising Kundalini to one's head helps purify one's mind which then leads to spiritual enlightenment..

Answer (score 0):

It's the other way around, enlightenment is attained after the kundalini rises to the sahaswara, and stays there. So the purpose of raja yoga is to have the kundalini slowly rise is a systematic safe way.

Comment: You should cite sources.